# linux copy symlinks and their hierarchy

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, symbolic-link

Say I have the following structure:

```
root
|
\
  dir1
  |
  | \
  |  libfoo.so.4.2
  |  libfoo.so.4 -> libfoo.so.4.2
  |  libfoo.so -> libfoo.so.4
     JunkThatShouldntBeCopied
  dir2
```

I would like to copy `libfoo.so` and using it also `libfoo.so.4` and `libfoo.so.4.2` into `root/dir2`.

- I can't copy the entire directory that contains them since it contains a lot of other files I do not want.
- I also don't know the exact names of the files that `libfoo.so` points to.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of something like this:

```
trace() {
  arr+=("$1")
  local next="$(readlink "$1")"
  if [ -n "$next" ]; then
    trace "$next"
  fi
}
```

```
$ cd /tmp/a/
$ unset arr; trace 3
$ rsync -vl "${arr[@]}" /tmp/b/
created directory /tmp/b
1
2 -> 1
3 -> 2

sent 125 bytes  received 70 bytes  390.00 bytes/sec
total size is 2  speedup is 0.01
$
```

Comment: Thanks! It's a good solution, but isn't there any native tool that can do what ```trace()``` does?

Comment: Not sure. I don't think so though. It doesn't always make sense either. (Consider links that points to file in an upper level directory.)

Answer (score 1):

`cp -Pp /root/dir1/libfoo.so* /root/dir2/`